# What are the differences between jQuery addClass and standard classList.addClass?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am not sure whether jQuery class methods (addClass, removeClass and toggleClass) act as a wrapper over the standard classList methods, they look pretty similar to me:

- http://api.jquery.com/addClass
- http://api.jquery.com/removeClass
- http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery's adds the class to every element in the jQuery collection, and is only usable on a jQuery collection. element.classList is only for one particular element, not a collection, and is only usable on a plain reference to an element.

With jQuery's `addClass` you can also supply a function to provide a variable class name to add.

If you already have jQuery in your project, feel free to use its version if you want, but there's nothing wrong with using the standard classList.addClass.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! 
True like many methods of jQuery work with the set of matched elements.

Comment: Also, for multiple classes, `element.classList()`accepts separate string parameters whereas `jQuery.addClass()` accepts a single, space-separated string.

Answer (score 1):

It could be a wrapper in supporting browsers; `classList` is a more recent API and was only supported by IE in 2012.

<sub>(Furthermore, i believe that jQuery should never be used.)</sub>

Comment: Thanks H.B: I haven't checked the jQuery source code, yet.
About jQuery, do you mean that it should not be used anymore because these days the browsers have all decent implementations of querySelector?

Comment: Yes, and not only that. Most of the useful functions (e.g. AJAX) now have convenient standard equivalents (which can be polyfilled if need be).

Comment: Thanks yes that was my point standard impl are widespread. I've checked the sources (full, not minified), no mention of classList and seems the implementation does not rely on any existing impl (this is really obvious wit the toggleClass function).